# If $ \left\{ A_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ is a *collection* of compact sets so that every finite subcollection has a nonempty intersection,

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1} A_n$ nonempty? Does the same apply for closed sets?

This question came up in review today in my Analysis I class, but no one was able to answer it before the period ended.

I do know that *nested* compact sets have a nonempty intersection because the subsequence contained in any $x_{n_k}$ has to be in $K_{n_0}$ and the limit $lim(x_{n_k})$ is an element of $K_{n_0}$ But what about the intersection of finite subcollections of compact sets? Note the problem does not specify that they are nested.

Thanks!

Comment: What space are the $A_n$ subsets of?  $\mathbb{R}$?  $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I do not know anything about spaces yet, they have not been discussed in my class as of yet.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Let $$B_N=\bigcap_{n=1}^N A_n.$$ Show that $B_N$ is a sequence of nested, compact, nonempty sets.

Comment: So you are saying to let $A_n$ be the collection of finite subsets whose intersections are non empty, and let $B_n$ be the intersection of all the $A_n$?

Comment: I am saying let $B_N$ be the intersection of the finite collection $A_1,...,A_N$. We know that $B_N$ is nonempty by hypothesis.

Comment: It seems the Heine-Borel Theorem may come in useful, i.e. if $K$ is compact, then every open cover for $K$ has a finite subcover. I could use this to show $B_n$ is both closed and bounded?

Comment: It is closed because it is the intersection of closed sets. It is bounded because it is a subset of $A_1$.

Comment: And if we replace "compact" with "closed" then it is no longer true, since the intersection of closed sets would be a closed set, which could be $\mathbb{N}$, which is not bounded?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The canonical example in the case of closed, but not compact is $A_n=[n,\infty).$